# Independent DSL files in Drools

Tags: drools, dsl, rules

I am using Drools 6.1.0.Final. I have 3 sets of rules, created with 3 different DSL files. Now, it seems that for every dslr file I create, all the DSL files are loaded into his scope, so if there are overlapping dsl definition in 2 different DSL files, they will conflict.

Is there a way to keep them separate?

It looks like there was a way: the "expander" keyword, but now it looks it has been deprecated (even though the Eclipse drools plugin still think it's useful and will not load other dsl files!).

Has the expander keyword been replaced with something else?

Answer (score 1):

The "expander" isn't supported since (at least) 5.1.1.

DRL files and therefore also DSLR files with their DSL files can be compiled separately and the resulting KiePackages can be combined into a single KieBase.

If you have any problems with a compilation in this manner add a comment to this answer.

Comment: can you share how you created the kie resource and session using dsl and dslr file. I am new to drools and I am able to execute rules using only drl files but I am running into problems when i try to use dsl and dslr files.